# Identify Gaps of Records in Date Range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

**Question:** I want to identify what Records do not have two records per day. Rank tells me if there's a second record for each day....

```
SELECT TR.tourid,
       TR.tourruntimestamp,
       TC.tourname,
       TC.tourfrequency,
       TC.unit,
       TC.division,
       RANK()
         OVER (
           PARTITION BY TR.tourid
           ORDER BY TR.tourruntimestamp) AS [Rank]
FROM   DBO.tbltourrun AS TR
       INNER JOIN DBO.tso_piml_tour_config AS TC
               ON TC.tourid = TR.tourid
WHERE  ( TC.tourfrequency = '2xDay' )
       AND ( TR.tourruntimestamp BETWEEN Dateadd(DAY, Datediff(DAY, 0, Getdate()) - 1, 0) AND Dateadd(DAY, Datediff(DAY, 0, Getdate()), 0) )
```

[image: ScreenShot of Results]

Comment: Ben, this is not clear. Please put the technical stuff aside for a minute and explain in simple words what are you dealing with and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to identify what records don't have 2 Records per day, and 4 records per day. See my Simplified question.

Comment: Please read the following article on [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More general answer. I don't know what do you want to do with weeks, months etc.

```
select      *

from       (SELECT        TR.TourID, TR.TourRunTimeStamp, TC.tourName, TC.tourFrequency, TC.Unit, TC.Division
                         ,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TR.TourID) AS cnt
            FROM            dbo.tblTourRun AS TR INNER JOIN
                                     dbo.TSO_PIML_Tour_Config AS TC ON TC.tourID = TR.TourID
            WHERE           TR.TourRunTimeStamp  BETWEEN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
            ) t

where       cnt <> case TC.tourFrequency when '1xDay' then 1 when '2xDay' then 2 when '4xDay' then 4 end
;
```

---

```
select      *

from       (SELECT        TR.TourID, TR.TourRunTimeStamp, TC.tourName, TC.tourFrequency, TC.Unit, TC.Division, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TR.TourID) AS cnt
            FROM            dbo.tblTourRun AS TR INNER JOIN
                                     dbo.TSO_PIML_Tour_Config AS TC ON TC.tourID = TR.TourID
            WHERE        (TC.tourFrequency = '2xDay') AND (TR.TourRunTimeStamp  BETWEEN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
            ) t

where       cnt = 1
;
```

Comment: Each has his own way of formatting SQL, but I'm not particularly fond of yours. May I suggest [this formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)?

Comment: @TT.  **(1))** all clause's keywords (select,from,where,group by,having,order by,qualify) appear one under the other, left aligned. **(2)** the format emphasises patterns. e.g. analytic functions with the same window will be one under the other, each in one line, even if it is a very long line.  **(3)** complicated expressions are being split to multiple lines by their parts. **(4)** space. I don't care about seeing the whole code in one screen I want to see the building blocks as clear as possible. **P.s.** I took Ben's original code and just wrapped it so it would be more easy for him.

Comment: Hey, like I said, to each their own :)

Comment: I also need to identify TourRuns that have no Timestamp for the day, because they are also not compliant? Any Ideas?

Comment: @Ben_Coding for both WHERE (inner and outer query) add `and TourRunTimeStamp is null `

Comment: I want to capture the Nulls and the ones with Timestamps.

Comment: `select *
from (SELECT TR.TourID, TR.TourRunTimeStamp, TC.tourName, TC.tourFrequency, TC.Unit, TC.Division
 ,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TR.TourID) AS cnt
 FROM dbo.tblTourRun AS TR INNER JOIN
 dbo.TSO_PIML_Tour_Config AS TC ON TC.tourID = TR.TourID
 WHERE TR.TourRunTimeStamp BETWEEN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
 or TR.TourRunTimeStamp is null
 ) t
where cnt <> case TC.tourFrequency when '1xDay' then 1 when '2xDay' then 2 when '4xDay' then 4 end
 or TR.TourRunTimeStamp is null;`

Answer (score 1):

Below is a contrived example that should get you in the right direction. I use a table of made up values to simulate the shape of the data you're trying to work with (stripping the values that aren't relevant for the example).

```
select a.TourId
     , b.TourDate
from (values
    (1, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2016-01-01 00:00:00'))
  , (1, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2016-01-01 04:00:00'))
  , (1, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2016-01-03 00:00:00'))
  , (1, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2016-01-04 00:00:00'))
  , (1, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2016-01-04 04:00:00'))
  , (1, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2016-01-05 00:00:00'))
  , (2, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2016-02-11 00:00:00'))
  , (2, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2016-02-11 18:00:00'))
  , (2, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2016-02-13 00:00:00'))
  , (2, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2016-02-14 00:00:00'))
  , (2, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2016-02-14 18:00:00'))
  , (2, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2016-02-15 00:00:00'))
) as a (TourId, TourRunTimeStamp)
cross apply (values(Convert(date, a.TourRunTimeStamp))) as b (TourDate)
group by a.TourId
       , b.TourDate
having Count(1) != 2; -- find ids with exactly two entries
-- having Count(1) in (2, 4); -- find ids with exactly two or four entries
-- having Count(1) % 2 = 0; -- find ids with an even number of entries
```

The logic here is simple: convert the datetime to a date (*this is done in an APPLY clause so that we can reuse the calculation*), group on the `TourId` + `TourDate`, count the number of records, and filter out all results that don't have a count equal to two.

Answer (score 0):

> Final SQL Results: 
>   With the Help of some CTE's or Views I was able to get it working.

1. Query 1- Tours ran between date range (Yesterday)
2. Query 2- Summary showing Tours with No Datestamp as Null on Datestamp Column
3. Query 3- Conditional Count when Tour is Missed so I show 0 for Missed Routes

---

```
`--Get All ToursRanYesterday 
WITH toursranyesterday 
     AS (SELECT TR.tourid, 
                TR.tourruntimestamp, 
                TC.tourname, 
                TC.division, 
                TC.unit, 
                TC.tourfrequency 
         FROM   dbo.tbltourrun AS TR 
                INNER JOIN dbo.tso_piml_tour_config AS TC 
                        ON TC.tourid = TR.tourid 
         WHERE  ( TC.tourfrequency LIKE '%xDay%' ) 
                AND ( TR.tourruntimestamp 
                      BETWEEN Dateadd(day, Datediff(day, 
                                   0,Getdate()) - 1, 0) 
                                                  AND 
                      Dateadd(day, Datediff(day, 
                                   0, Getdate()), 0) )), 
     --Get Summary of xDay Tours Ran with Missing Tours 
     toursummary 
     AS (SELECT TC.tourid, 
                TC.division, 
                TC.unit, 
                TC.tourname, 
                TC.tourfrequency, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                 FROM   toursranyesterday AS TY 
                                 WHERE  TC.tourid = TY.tourid) THEN 'NO' 
                    WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                     FROM   toursranyesterday AS TY 
                                     WHERE  TC.tourid = TY.tourid) THEN 'YES' 
                  END ) AS Missed, 
                TY.tourruntimestamp 
         FROM   dbo.tso_piml_tour_config AS TC 
                FULL OUTER JOIN toursranyesterday AS TY 
                             ON TY.tourid = TC.tourid 
         WHERE  ( TC.tourfrequency LIKE '%xDay%' )) 
--Add Daily Tour Count when Missed = NO 
SELECT TS.tourid, 
       TS.division, 
       TS.unit, 
       TS.tourname, 
       TS.tourfrequency, 
       TS.missed, 
       TS.tourruntimestamp, 
       Count(CASE 
               WHEN missed = 'NO' THEN 1 
               ELSE NULL 
             END) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY TS.tourid) AS [DailyTourCount] 
FROM   toursummary AS TS 
ORDER  BY TS.tourname `
```